# Linearity assumptions

Tags: multiple-regression, assumptions

I am doing a multiple regression analysis with 5 controlling variables, and I have many models (some of them are significant and some are not). For the reporting, should I test the regression assumptions for all these models (even if they are not significant)?

Comment: What are your models and how did you arrive at five? What exactly do you mean by "the model is not significant"?

Comment: Reporting always depends on who is the audience, and whether there are specific requirements in your field/reporting environment.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHennig, sorry for making it a bit "unclear". By "significant", I meant that regression unstandardized coefficients were significant (as well as the F-test). There is no particular requirement in the field. But to publish a work, I assume reviewers would wonder about assumptions

Comment: I would hope that *you* would be the first one to wonder about the assumptions, before the reviewers ever looked at the work.  This suggests you ought to pursue this thought if only to make sure your analyses are meaningful.